# Overlay of text along path

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, nodes, overlays, paths

In beamer, I failed to show the text above a path from the second slide on using the overlay specification like `<2->` and `onslide<2->`. How to do that?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    % Error: giving up on this path
    \draw (0,0) to node<2-> [sloped, above = 5pt] {text} (1,1);
    % Error: giving up on this path
    \draw (0,0) to \onslide<2->{node [sloped, above = 5pt] {text}} (1,1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No problem with `overlay-beamer-styles`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) to node [visible on=<2->,sloped, above = 5pt] {text} (1,1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: i wasn't aware of the `tikz` library `overlay-beamer-styles`. where it is documented?

Comment: @Zarko `texdoc aobs`.

Comment: thank you very much for info. it seems to be valuable source information. +1 for that!